# How to average with errors in spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

i tried to average cells that include one or more errors in google spreadsheet, seems =average(D:D) is not working. how to avoid those errors?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(D:D))
```

Comment: nice, it's working! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may try `AVERAGEIF()` function like-

```
=AVERAGEIF(D:D,">0")
```

Above formula will ignore error values.

Comment: nice, it's working! Thanks!

Comment: @koronkasin If it works then you should accept the answer. Tick mark it.